# Color management in blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, color, color-management

Color Management used to be in the "Scene" tab. But now it's gone. Where did it go?

Answer (score 1):

It is still in the scene section.

[image]

Comment: Technically, this is the render settings section. The "scene" section still exists, and is the 4th tab down in your screenshot.